# Python - Send and Receive of UDP packets

Tags: python, sockets, udp, send

I've started with Python a few month ago. Now I've reached a point where I need some help concerning networking.
I've the following scenario:

- One PC and 3 external devices in a small local net.
- The PC wants to observe a switch state (on/off) on each device. This will be done by an initial command from the PC to each device.
- After receiving this command each device sends automatically a packet with the new state to the PC whenever the switch state has changed.
- All the packets on the network are UDP packets

On the PC I have the following Python script running (just for one device):

```
import socket

UDP_IP1 = "192.168.1.64"
UDP_IP2 = "192.168.1.73"
UDP_IP3 = "192.168.1.74"
UDP_PORT = 45           # used port on external device

port = 52129

message = "Message to observe..."      # not the real command string

def SendData():
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  
        s.bind(("", port))
        msg = message.encode('utf-8')
        s.sendto(msg, (UDP_IP1, UDP_PORT))
    except:
        print("Sending Error!!!\n")

    return s

def ReceiveData(sock):
    print("Receiving data: \n")

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)      # buffer size is 4096 bytes
        print ("received message:", data)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    s = SendData()
    ReceiveData(s)
```

**My Problem:** In principal this script is running, but after approximately 2 minutes without any change of the switch on the device I do not receive any more packets from the external device when the switch state changes. But I can see the incoming packets with the installed Wireshark.

It looks like a time-out when I don't receive anything but 'sock.recvfrom' is still waiting for data.

Is there anyone who has/had the same problem?